# ASP MVC4 jquery calendar

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP MVC4 jquery calendar. I'm new to this. I have my jquery calendar built so that it highlights particular dates which i passed through array. But now the question is, I have a table of data in database which I got into Model and then used to it retrieve information based on an 'ID' in controller and returned to VIEW. Now I can get the dates from database in the form of table but I want to know, how I can pass those particular dates to an array of JQUERY CALENDAR in VIEW.

Also I imported package:
 with core and datepicker functionalities.

But when i click the next arrow or previous arrow, it doesn't show next or previous months.

I can post the code if you don't understand my question. Please help me since I have already spent more than 15 days understanding this.

Comment: please post some code, in particular how you initialise the datepickers

Answer (score 1):

well, thats an older question but I had a couple of problem myself with datepicker and took me about 3 hours of research until I found the answer ... this is only for poeple like me who'd end up on this while digging up for answers ... *

Jquery UI is already include in .net mvc4, as is datepicker, its in the bundle. you just have to call it by adding this to your layout ( in the head section )

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
```

also, make sure you dont have another script render at the bottom of your body, as its by default where the jquery bundle is set (at least it was for me on the default project ) and it cause a bug with datepicker when I used it.

```
<input id="mydate" name="mydate" class="datepicker" type="text" value="@Model.mydate.Value.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")" />
```

where mydate is the name of the parameter you'll have set in your viewModel, said parameter is a DateTime object ( or DateTimeOffSet ) (the .Value is only if you set the date as a nullable, its not necessary otherwise)

After on the bottom of your view, create a jquery section :

```
@section scripts{
<script>

$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, d MM yy", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

</script>
}
```

(dateformat and altformat are optional, give them the value you want or dont use them at all)

as for the array of date ... i'd use a viewmodel, which would contains your array as parameter, and pass this viewmodel between your view and your controller. after that define an Editor template and its should be pretty straighforward to build a table with the dates from there.